# Short-hand assignment to lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have declared a (5x6) list called path in Python as:

```
path = [[' ']*6]*5
```

Now, when I change the value of any one element as:

```
path[4][5] = '*'
```

or

```
path[0][5] = '*'
```

I get the output as:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*']
```

That is, all the elements of the specified column get changed to '*'. Why does this happen?
My guess is that maybe this has something to do with the way this short-hand notation is implemented in Python. Maybe the interpreter takes the first row and copies it down for all columns.

Comment: You are exactly right, you have 5 duplicates of the initial list and so changes to any item in any will propogate throughout the structure

Comment: I am confused though as to why your output is full of blanks and not 0s

Comment: I'm sorry, I entered a zero in the list my mistake. It was supposed to be a space.